# cannot connect database

Tags: database

im new with wordpress. im planning to connect wordpress database from my own php code . but i get problem when trying to connect database, everytime i connect always get error result. im using this code

```
$user_name = "myusername";
$password = "password";
$database = "mydatabasename";
$host_name = "localhost";

$connect_db=mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password);

$find_db=mysqli_select_db($database);

if ($find_db) {
 echo "Database found";
 mysqli_close($connect_db);
}
else {
 echo "Database notfound";
 mysqli_close($connect_db);
}
```

Comment: What error do you get exactly?

Answer (score 1):

While it may possible to connect using mysqli->connect it is always better to make use of built in Wordpress functionality (even for external code).

By this I mean that you should use the wpdb class. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb for more information.

First you need to link to the Wordpress class:

```
echo '<h1>WP Connect DB</h1>';
echo '<p>Directory Check: '.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php</p>';
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );
```

If you get an error, check that the path to wp-load is correct and adjust if necessary.

Next you can define the user and database etc.

```
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'mydatabase');
/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'myusername');
/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypassword');
/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

This info comes straight from the wp-config.php file. These do not need to be defined as constants, you can submit these directly into the right place in the database connection code below:

```
$wpdb = new wpdb( DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
```

Finally you can do something with the results for example:

```
$rows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_posts" );
echo '<h3>Results</h3><pre>'.var_export($rows,true).'</pre>';
```

Putting it all together your code would look like this:

```
echo '<h1>WP Connect DB</h1>';
echo '<p>Directory: '.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wpdev/wp-load.php</p>';
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wpdev/wp-load.php' );
define('SHORTINIT', true );
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'mydatabase');
/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'myusername');
/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypassword');
/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
$wpdb = new wpdb( DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
$rows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_posts" );
echo '<h3>Results</h3><pre>'.var_export($rows,true).'</pre>';
```

The additional SHORTINIT definition is added to minimise the Wordpress load but is not required.

I hope that this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb). It's the built in class for handling external databases.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need connect to database but implement wordpress functions on custom code ?

Just include wp-config.php file on custom code and you can use all wordpress functions.

```
<?php

require_once('wp-config.php');

$posts = new WP_Query(...);
```

after that you can use wordpress [wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) class

```
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id, name FROM mytable" );
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to do custom mysql connection, you can include wp-blog-header.php file and get all wp functionality working in your PHP file:

```
<?php require 'PATH-TO-WP/wp-blog-header.php'; ?>
```